# Reference to Statistical Control Quality

Tags: self-study, references, quality-control

This semester I'm taking a Green Belt course. I'm really enjoying it and I want to go more deeper in that, I already take this book to start to study

[Introduction to Statistical Quality Control](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0470169923)

does anyone know any more reference on the subject, or even online videos.

Thank you.

Comment: There is a supplement available: http://www.wiley.com/college/bcs/0471316482/add/s_index.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May be you can get some useful things in the book [Design and Analysis of Experiments](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1118146921), by the same author. It not only introduces some more advance techniques such as Factorial design, block and confounding, but also cover some materials in the level between, such as one-way anova and two-way anova.

There is a good thing in this book. A lot of examples using MINITAB are available in a [companion book](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1118342275).

Comment: I already take a course in Design and Analysis of experiments with this textbook, but thank you anyway.